# How to figure out what code include'd specified .php file?

Tags: php

I have a third-party web server with Ubuntu 14.04 and PHP 5.5.3 running some wordpress stuff. Using logs I figured out what some `.php` file seems to be a part of a backdoor/spambot and sending a spam. But according to website architecture this file must not be included at all. I can add code to that file and require a stacktrace:

```
$e = new Exception;
file_put_contents('/tmp/debug.log', $e->getTraceAsString());
```

But stacktrace contains only:

```
#0 {main}
```

It seems that file is included or required from a top-level scope. Is it any way for me to figure out where a file is required from? Like name of `.php` file and a line where `require` or `include` is called?

**Update**

Since I have two answers suggesting `debug_backtrace` I must clarify that it's same as `getTraceAsString` and evaluates to an empty array (I tested it manually).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your stacktrace is always empty (and assuming you verified that correctly) then you may alternatively take a look at `$_SERVER` upon requests of your infected file. Maybe it isn't included by another php-file, e. g. called from the command line or is somehow directly requested.

```
file_put_contents('/tmp/debug.log', print_r($_SERVER, TRUE));
```

Especially take a look at the following values:

- `argv` and `REMOTE_ADDR` (127.0.0.1?) to make sure that the script is not called over the command line.
- `REQUEST_URI`, `QUERY_STRING`, `SCRIPT_NAME` and `REQUEST_METHOD` to find out from which URL your script gets called.
- `HTTP_REFERER` to find out from where users come from that access your script (assuming that it is somehow called upon pageviews of your website).

Another option would be to use a recursive `grep` over all subdirectories of your website on your webserver to search for files that contain the name of the infected file:

```
grep -rl "your_infected_file.php" /path/to/your/website/folder
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was a culprit, file was accessible from outside and requested from some remote pc.

Answer (score 1):

Using `debug_backtrace`, you will be able to see the `require` and `include`.

Comment: But isn't `debug_backtrace` same as `getTraceAsString`?

Comment: I have checked `debug_backtrace`, it evaluates to empty array.

Comment: How do you verify that?

Answer (score 1):

PHP's [debug-backtrace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) function returns an array with the complete backtrace, you can use it like this is your offending backdoor/spambot `.php` files to figure out where they are being called:

```
file_put_contents('/tmp/debug.log', print_r(debug_backtrace(), TRUE));
```

Alternatively you can use the [debug-print-backtrace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-print-backtrace.php) function like this:

```
file_put_contents('/tmp/debug.log', debug_print_backtrace());
```

Comment: As I already commented, `debug_backtrace` evaluates to an empty array.

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar problem and hopefully my solution will help you too.
Given that I have a project of 300+ .php source files I wanted to know what is the set S of .php files that my file F depends on.

All you need to do is to

1. scan the project directory and for each .php file you need to parse the file's content for those includes|requires statements then extract those filenames and
2. create a graph with all this information.

By using Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm determine what's the shortest path between one chosen file any other file of the project. So basically you'll get a dependency tree that will tell you more than you need.

@Edit: if interested then [read more about this](http://mynixworld.info/2015/04/16/php-file-dependencies-tree/).

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a list of php files that have been included/required then [there's a function for that](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-included-files.php).

I've never used it before, but from that page:

```
<?php
// This file is abc.php

include 'test1.php';
include_once 'test2.php';
require 'test3.php';
require_once 'test4.php';

$included_files = get_included_files();

foreach ($included_files as $filename) {
    echo "$filename\n";
}
```

The above example will output:

```
abc.php
test1.php
test2.php
test3.php
test4.php
```

It's worth noting though, that unless you know otherwise, the spam bot thing is unlikely to be in a separate PHP file, it'll likely be an edited one.

If possible, rebuilding the site (if you're using something like ant or phing) should make the problem go away so long as your source code hasn't been compromised. Of course you still need to work out how they did it in the first place.